# "A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client" when accessed by GoogleBot, but not by direct link

Tags: asp.net, url, httprequest, elmah

I have ELMAH installed, and recently was checking the error log.  I found out quite a lot of

```
System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (?).
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateInputIfRequiredByConfig()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ValidateHelper(HttpContext context)
```

The headers are as below:

```
Connection: Keep-alive Accept: */* Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate From: googlebot(at)googlebot.com Host: xxxxxxxxxxxxx User-Agent: Googlebot-Image/1.0
```

So I assume it is being accessed by Google.

The URL in questoin is `/uploads/EventData/MediaItems/Normal/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx-d65efc194d3849a98f5481452be59719.jpg?v=1`.

When I try to access that URL myself manually, it works fine without any errors.  What I've noticed is that the `PATH_TRANSLATED` variable reported by ELMAH is:

```
c:\websites\tmp\xxxxxxxxxxxxxx\www\deploy\uploads\EventData\MediaItems\Normal\xxxxxxxxxxxxxx-d65efc194d3849a98f5481452be59719.jpg?v=1
```

I add the `?v=1` querystring parameter so that files are versioned, and if a new file is updated, the version is incremented.  As far as I know, that shouldn't be a problem, right?

My main issue is that I cannot replicate this error, but it definitely is happening as ELMAH is logging it.

Comment: Did you get around this error? I get intermitten errors like this when using image resizer with `/Photo-002994-634632774600377727.jpg?width=100&height=100&mode=crop` ?

Comment: No, still not.  My thought is something related to Url-encoding, but I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 0):

'Potentially dangerous request' generally occur when the bots are crawling through the site or some hacker is trying to inject the URL to find out vulnerabilities. It is not really anything critical to worry about.

One can replicate it by adding `*` to the url for regex match.

You can chuck this error by adding an error filter.